# ASCII Art comments in C/C++ headers and code files

Tags: c++, c, ascii, sublimetext

I watched with great interest the [Mojang "Mojam" for Humble Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) (link might not be valid for a long time), and throughout the video, I saw some great things on how these guys use their code.

One of these things was that one of the developer use ascii art comments in his code to better navigate around.

This gives something like this:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
//      ___  ___       ___   _   __   _    //
//     /   |/   |     /   | | | |  \ | |   //
//    / /|   /| |    / /| | | | |   \| |   //
//   / / |__/ | |   / / | | | | | |\   |   //
//  / /       | |  / /  | | | | | | \  |   //
// /_/        |_| /_/   |_| |_| |_|  \_|   //
//                                         //
/////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    // do some stuff
    return 0;
}
```

This may look bad right there, but associated with editors like [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), it becomes powerful, because the "zoomed out" view that Sublime exposes lets you read that text and navigate in your code like a breeze.

Now, there are plenty of cool ascii art text generators [out there](https://www.google.com/?q=ascii%20text%20generator).
But none of these (at least those I looked at) generate C++/C compliant text.

Meaning: I have to manually add the comment slashes (`//`) all around to make it go along in the code.

Do you guys use this trick?
If yes, do you have a tool to generate these "comments" around the text?

Comment: Not to sound like too much of a killjoy, and Sublime Text is really great-looking, but doesn't it make more sense to *search programmatically* for e.g. `main()`, rather than decorating it so that you can more quickly search manually, i.e. by looking?

Comment: @unwind: Looking for an identifier I definitely agree.  But sometimes code files are segmented by categories, like "private members here".  Of course, you can still put those category names into ordinary comments and use find.

Comment: Agree with unwind there; vgrep is far inferior to grep.

Comment: @unwind: people find different methods helpful, plus with Sublimes side-file-map (it's got a better name but I can't think of it) you can visually grep what the functions are in a big source by having the chunky ACSII comments.

Comment: @unwind: well I do use file search when I know what I'm looking for. But sometimes I also look where to put the implementation of a method I just declared in my header, and I just scroll and scroll, visually looking for the "private methods" section. This is exactly what the ASCII art header is supposed to solve :)

Comment: The wonders people do when working with hard-to-parse languages...

Comment: i don't think that this will ease your work, this is just decorating, it doesn't need

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis: try foraging through a 5k lines python file, that's no better!

Comment: May I disagree with you? I have a 1KLoc C++ file where I have some mixed code (static functions, 2 classes, public/private members, ...) that is quite hard to navigate through. I won't split it in two files because the 2 classes are deeply linked and it makes sens to have them in one file. Now, using this kind of "visual hint" is essential when I'm shuffling in it. It definitely improved my navigation!

Comment: I think an editor that supports `#pragma mark` with a navigation menu and filtering is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Use a modern IDE with code browser functionality (Visual Studio for example) and such things are entirely unnecessary (if they ever were necessary).  If you worked for me and put that in your code you would not work for me for long! ;-)

Comment: if it is really need, you may use it, but it is not essential

Comment: Exactly. Folks are so used to grepping with regexps the languages that no regexp can parse, and then this ASCII art thing, that they forget that it shouldn't be this way with proper tool support.

Comment: With Sublime Text 2, this is silly. Simply use the "Goto symbol..." feature to navigate to `main`. So cmd+r/ctrl+r and then type "main" to navigate directly there. Or just type cmd+p => "@main".

Comment: This only works when you're searching for a specific thing. When I want to add a new method implementation, for instance, I like to place it in the right section, at the end of the others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes I use to add those kinds of "nav" cues. Specially in communication parts which has many similar parts but handle i.e. different message types.

I work on a Mac so here goes my setup.

Previously I used a dashboard widget
http://memention.com/figlet/

But my latest thing is to create a Service with Automator and install `figlet` with homebrew. Then in the Service I have this one-liner (also clicked "Output replaces selected text")

```
/usr/local/bin/figlet -f smslant -w 132
```

Now in any App I can have figlets just by right-clicking some text.

My preferred font is `smslant`

Then I usually just add `/*` and `*/` after.

### Edit

Well, I just updated my Service to add that C comment

```
( echo "/*" ; /usr/local/bin/figlet -f smslant -w 132 ; echo " */" )
```

Comment: I'll take your answer, which is close to what I'll do (Linux here). Althoug Warren has a point... I guess. Everybody has his own preferences :)

Comment: If you prefer `//` style comments, try this: `/usr/local/bin/figlet -f smslant -w 132 | sed -e 's/^/\/\/ /'`

Answer (score 13):

Recently, when I was searching something in my .php file with list of routes for a site, I've decided to make such big ASCII comments. And now, I use them (not in all source files, but for example in long config files), and these comments really help to navigate.

Here is how it looks in my Sublime *Minimap*:

[image]

So far, I didn't automate the process of creating such comments. I use online ASCII creator from [this site](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/). I use font "basic"

Comment: That's what I'm talking about!!

Comment: `#pragma mark` in XCode is so much nicer than your zoom out view.

Comment: I've added a link to github plugin (it's a draft, but it's working for me)

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, [ASCII Decorator](https://github.com/viisual/ASCII-Decorator) is a SublimeText 3 plugin that does "automate" this and includes the "basic" font.

Answer (score 8):

NO. I don't use such things and would find such things worse than useless.  Screen = bandwidth. Wasting space like this decreases code readability.

```
            ______
||\   ||   /      \
|| \  ||   |      |
||  \ ||   |      |
||   \||   \______/
```

:-)

Comment: I kinda want to downvote purely as there's no one 'right' way to code. Making it worse for *you* is subjective, personally I find it worse to code in vim but I've been told plenty of times it's the most efficient editor known in the explored universe, but I don't advise people against using it.

Comment: There may be no 'right' way to code, but there are many 'wrong' ways and this is definitely one of them.

Comment: The longer I do this, the more I wish for short, concise, readable CODE. Comments (not in big ASCII art) are okay, even good. But that doesn't make my corporate Code into "a place for my doodles".

Comment: This is one of those cases where no one cares if you don't use it, we only care if you do (and if so, what tool?) The OP did not actually intend for everyone who dislikes this method to come in here and start a holy war, nor is this what Stack Overflow is for. I'm tempted to downvote for not only not answering the question, but for cluttering up the answer space with opinionated and unhelpful comments.

Comment: The question itself narrowly gets past the "Does this belong on SO?" filter, as the OP was not actually asking your opinion about this practice, but asking for tools to facilitate this practice in C/C++

Comment: I'm sure eventually the No Fun Police will delete this.

Comment: While I agree that screen real estate is at a premium for coding, ASCII-art comments can still be helpful to separate functional sections within a source file for faster navigation. When used like this, the additional screen real estate only separates function sections, having little or no impact on how much code-of-interest that can fit on the screen. For me, this is rare because I prefer to split functional sections of code into multiple files, but on rare occasions ASCII comments are the better/only option.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SublimeText, I suggest to try [ASCII Decorator](https://github.com/viisual/ASCII-Decorator). It's easy to install it, it doesn't require anything else than Sublime and it works on every OS.
Plus, it has a lot of nice fonts!

Comment: Thanks!
There's also a vscode port called ASCIIDecorator

Comment: link to ASCIIDecorator for VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=helixquar.asciidecorator

Answer (score 0):

try an IDE that supports #pragma mark?
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html